# Xcode 10.1 is crashing while tapping the error MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos-mojave, xcode10.1

Xcode 10 is crashing while tapping the error in the project navigator. I tried changing the WokSpace settings to "New Build System" and "Legacy Build System" but did not work out. This is the error I get.

When clicking on this linker error Xcode keeps crashing. Please help me fix this out. I am working on a project which is in Swift 4.

[image]